# Encode64 / Decode64 in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6

Sorry for this long post, but is there perhaps a simply equivalent to this VB6 code in .NET already implemented? Thank you very much.

```
Public Function Encode64(sString As String) As String

    Dim bTrans(63) As Byte, lPowers8(255) As Long, lPowers16(255) As Long, bout() As Byte, bIn() As Byte
    Dim lChar As Long, lTrip As Long, iPad As Integer, lLen As Long, lTemp As Long, lPos As Long, lOutSize As Long

    For lTemp = 0 To 63                                 'Fill the translation table.
        Select Case lTemp
            Case 0 To 25
                bTrans(lTemp) = 65 + lTemp              'A - Z
            Case 26 To 51
                bTrans(lTemp) = 71 + lTemp              'a - z
            Case 52 To 61
                bTrans(lTemp) = lTemp - 4               '1 - 0
            Case 62
                bTrans(lTemp) = 43                      'Chr(43) = "+"
            Case 63
                bTrans(lTemp) = 47                      'Chr(47) = "/"
        End Select
    Next lTemp

    For lTemp = 0 To 255                                'Fill the 2^8 and 2^16 lookup tables.
        lPowers8(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp8
        lPowers16(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp16
    Next lTemp

    iPad = StrLen(sString) Mod 3                           'See if the length is divisible by 3
    If iPad Then                                        'If not, figure out the end pad and resize the input.
        iPad = 3 - iPad
        sString = sString & String(iPad, Chr(0))
    End If

    bIn = StrConv(sString, vbFromUnicode)               'Load the input string.
    lLen = ((UBound(bIn) + 1) \ 3) * 4                  'Length of resulting string.
    lTemp = lLen \ 72                                   'Added space for vbCrLfs.
    lOutSize = ((lTemp * 2) + lLen) - 1                 'Calculate the size of the output buffer.
    ReDim bout(lOutSize)                                'Make the output buffer.

    lLen = 0                                            'Reusing this one, so reset it.

    For lChar = LBound(bIn) To UBound(bIn) Step 3
        lTrip = lPowers16(bIn(lChar)) + lPowers8(bIn(lChar + 1)) + bIn(lChar + 2)    'Combine the 3 bytes
        lTemp = lTrip And clOneMask                     'Mask for the first 6 bits
        bout(lPos) = bTrans(lTemp \ cl2Exp18)           'Shift it down to the low 6 bits and get the value
        lTemp = lTrip And clTwoMask                     'Mask for the second set.
        bout(lPos + 1) = bTrans(lTemp \ cl2Exp12)       'Shift it down and translate.
        lTemp = lTrip And clThreeMask                   'Mask for the third set.
        bout(lPos + 2) = bTrans(lTemp \ cl2Exp6)        'Shift it down and translate.
        bout(lPos + 3) = bTrans(lTrip And clFourMask)   'Mask for the low set.
        If lLen = 68 Then                               'Ready for a newline
            bout(lPos + 4) = 13                         'Chr(13) = vbCr
            bout(lPos + 5) = 10                         'Chr(10) = vbLf
            lLen = 0                                    'Reset the counter
            lPos = lPos + 6
        Else
            lLen = lLen + 4
            lPos = lPos + 4
        End If
    Next lChar

    If bout(lOutSize) = 10 Then lOutSize = lOutSize - 2 'Shift the padding chars down if it ends with CrLf.

    If iPad = 1 Then                                    'Add the padding chars if any.
        bout(lOutSize) = 61                             'Chr(61) = "="
    ElseIf iPad = 2 Then
        bout(lOutSize) = 61
        bout(lOutSize - 1) = 61
    End If

    Encode64 = StrConv(bout, vbUnicode)                 'Convert back to a string and return it.

End Function

Public Function Decode64(sString As String) As String

    Dim bout() As Byte, bIn() As Byte, bTrans(255) As Byte, lPowers6(63) As Long, lPowers12(63) As Long
    Dim lPowers18(63) As Long, lQuad As Long, iPad As Integer, lChar As Long, lPos As Long, sOut As String
    Dim lTemp As Long

    sString = Replace(sString, vbCr, vbNullString)      'Get rid of the vbCrLfs.  These could be in...
    sString = Replace(sString, vbLf, vbNullString)      'either order.

    lTemp = StrLen(sString) Mod 4                          'Test for valid input.
    If lTemp Then
        Call Err.Raise(vbObjectError, "MyDecode", "Input string is not valid Base64.")
    End If

    If InStrRev(sString, "==") Then                     'InStrRev is faster when you know it's at the end.
        iPad = 2                                        'Note:  These translate to 0, so you can leave them...
    ElseIf InStrRev(sString, "=") Then                  'in the string and just resize the output.
        iPad = 1
    End If

    For lTemp = 0 To 255                                'Fill the translation table.
        Select Case lTemp
            Case 65 To 90
                bTrans(lTemp) = lTemp - 65              'A - Z
            Case 97 To 122
                bTrans(lTemp) = lTemp - 71              'a - z
            Case 48 To 57
                bTrans(lTemp) = lTemp + 4               '1 - 0
            Case 43
                bTrans(lTemp) = 62                      'Chr(43) = "+"
            Case 47
                bTrans(lTemp) = 63                      'Chr(47) = "/"
        End Select
    Next lTemp

    For lTemp = 0 To 63                                 'Fill the 2^6, 2^12, and 2^18 lookup tables.
        lPowers6(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp6
        lPowers12(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp12
        lPowers18(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp18
    Next lTemp

    bIn = StrConv(sString, vbFromUnicode)               'Load the input byte array.
    ReDim bout((((UBound(bIn) + 1) \ 4) * 3) - 1)       'Prepare the output buffer.

    For lChar = 0 To UBound(bIn) Step 4
        lQuad = lPowers18(bTrans(bIn(lChar))) + lPowers12(bTrans(bIn(lChar + 1))) + _
                lPowers6(bTrans(bIn(lChar + 2))) + bTrans(bIn(lChar + 3))           'Rebuild the bits.
        lTemp = lQuad And clHighMask                    'Mask for the first byte
        bout(lPos) = lTemp \ cl2Exp16                   'Shift it down
        lTemp = lQuad And clMidMask                     'Mask for the second byte
        bout(lPos + 1) = lTemp \ cl2Exp8                'Shift it down
        bout(lPos + 2) = lQuad And clLowMask            'Mask for the third byte
        lPos = lPos + 3
    Next lChar

    sOut = StrConv(bout, vbUnicode)                     'Convert back to a string.
    If iPad Then sOut = Left$(sOut, StrLen(sOut) - iPad)   'Chop off any extra bytes.
    Decode64 = sOut

End Function
```

Comment: You can no longer store binary data in a string.  You *must* use Byte() in vb.net.  If you ignore this then you'll find out that the data gets corrupted when .NET normalizes the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can use the native functions in .net with strings:

```
Public Shared Function EncodeString64(instr as string) as String
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(instr))
End function

Public Shared Function DecodeString64(encstr as string) as String
    Return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encstr))
End function
```

For unicode:

```
Public Shared Function EncodeString64(instr as string) as String
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(instr))
End function

Public Shared Function DecodeString64(encstr as string) as String
    Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encstr))
End function
```

Comment: Just replace `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII` with `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The VB6 code uses ANSI encoding. This might be important if the VB.Net is expected to behave exactly like the VB6, e.g. if it needs to read files written by the VB6. VB.Net equivalent is Encoding.Default

Comment: ANSI can mean a lot of things. It's historical use is in terminals where ASCII, which is 7-bit, is used for the first 128 characters, the upper 128 could be anything basically. Unless you know its code page for the upper part you can only find out by trying decoding the strings. Base64 is rather blind to this though so as long as they stay within byte width (1 byte for ascii/ansi, 2 for some unicode etc.) I don't believe it will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are native .NET functions to deal with this:

System.Convert.ToBase64String (encoding) and System.Convert.FromBase64String (decoding)

Comment: Thank you. But this accepts byte only, and I wanted to pass a string to it.